# LWJGL Mouse.getDX Always returns 0

Tags: java, lwjgl, mousemove

This is using LWJGL version 2.9.1, I am on windows 8.1 using a razer deatheradder mouse.

Whenever I call `Mouse.getDX()` or `Mouse.getDY()` it always returns 0 no matter how fast I move my mouse or how far.

`Mouse.getX()` works and `Mouse.getY()` works but `getDX` and `getDY` do not.

I have been attempting to recreate `getDX` and `getDY` for awhile but want to put this question up to see if it can get answered before I finish it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are calling `Mouse.setGrabbed(true);` per frame? I had this problem, after moving it out of the render loop, `getDX` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a reason to why Mouse.getDX and Mouse.getDY always return 0 but I thought I should share my version in case others have the same issue so they don't have to create their own:

```
/*----NOTES----
 *This requires two variables saved
 *somewhere named mouseX and mouseY 

 *I only give getDX() as they are identical, just swap
 *dX -> dY   
 *currentX -> currentY  
 *Mouse.getX() -> Mouse.getY()  
 *mouseX -> mouseY:*/

public int getDX(){
    int dX = 0;
    int currentX = Mouse.getX();

    /*This is is only used because I am 
     *running my update mouse when Mouse.
     *isGrabbed is true, this prevents it 
     *from jumping right after you click */
    if(mouseX == 0){
        mouseX = currentX;
    }

    dX = Math.abs(mouseX - currentX);

    //Handles left/right movement
    if(mouseX > currentX){
        dX = -dX;
    }

    /*If the mouse was to go too far in
     *either direction it resets it */
    if(currentX >= Main.WIDTH - 25){
        currentX = 0;
    }
    else if(currentX == 0){
        currentX = Main.WIDTH - 25;
    }else{
        mouseX = currentX;
    }

    return dX;
}
```